# Pytest a function that prints to stdout

Tags: python, pytest

```
def f(n):
    nuw = n.casefold()
    for i in ["a","e","i","o","u"]:
        nuw = nuw.replace(i,"")
    print(nuw)

if __name__=='__main__':
    ask = input("Word? ")
    f(ask)
```

Comment: Printing something to stdout is a side effect of a function. What is the point in testing a side effect? What is the point for this function to *print* the resulting list? Why not return it?

Comment: @pavel some users print to stdout then use bash utils like sed, awk, grep - that's perfectly fine

Comment: What are you trying to do? check the `print()` is working correctly or that your function is working correctly? instead of printing the result return it, that way you can test it.

Comment: i/o should be top down. In that sense you would pass in the print function and in unit tests you use something that writes to a buffer instead of stdout, for example. Or you return the value and print it at the top level.

Comment: @Guy, some users may (sometimes) use bash tools like sed, awk grep ... in addition, pytest found this scenario important enough to support it.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom, this is just not a great software design. A better practice is to have all of the side effects inside the `main()`, `run()`, etc,  while at the same time keeping all individual functions pure. If this is the only task that a script is designed for, ok, it's all right to print to console, but in vast majority of cases it's not a great practice.

Comment: @pavel I agree, it is usually better to have functions return values. it *is* a better design. I'm just saying that in *some* cases I can see a benefit from having a standalone script that tests its stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution according to the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/capture-stdout-stderr.html):

```
def f(n):
    nuw = n.casefold()
    for i in ["a","e","i","o","u"]:
        nuw = nuw.replace(i,"")
    print(nuw)

def test_my_func_f(capsys):  # or use "capfd" for fd-level
    f("oren")
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == "rn\n"
```

When you run it, it goes smooth:

```
$ pytest --capture=sys main.py 
================================================== test session starts ===================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/oren/Downloads/LLL
collected 1 item                                                                                                         

main.py .                                                                                                          [100%]

=================================================== 1 passed in 0.01s ====================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's totally possible to test what's actually sent to stdout, it's not the recommended way.

Instead, design your functions so that they return their results. I.e., they have no *side effects*, as another commenter wrote. The advantage is, functions like these ("pure functions") are extremely easy to test: it simply gives you output — and it should be the same output for the same input every time.

And then, finally, to actually produce output from your program, do the IO in the top-level. E.g., in `main()` or some other top-level function/file. And sure, you *can* test this as well, if it's important. But I find that testing the lower level functions (which is silly easy to do) gives me enough confidence that my code works.